# Why didn't Han Solo become a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, han-solo

Han Solo says in *A New Hope*,

> I've flown from one side of this galaxy to the other, and I've seen a lot of strange stuff, but I've never seen *anything* to make me believe that there's one all-powerful Force controlling everything. 'Cause no mystical energy field controls *my* destiny. It's all a lot of simple tricks and nonsense.

In *Empire Strikes Back*,

[image]

He's holding a lightsaber, to open the Tauntaun's stomach and sticks Luke into the Tauntaun's abdominal cavity to temporarily keep Luke warm while he sets up the shelter.

In *The Force Awakens*, he says to Rey,

> I used to wonder about that myself. Thought it was a bunch of mumbo-jumbo. A magical power holding together good and evil, the dark side and the light. Crazy thing is... it's true. The Force. The Jedi... All of it... It's all true.

Now going back to the question, **why didn't Han Solo ever become a Jedi during the events of the original trilogy?** Kidding aside, for Star Wars fans, they wish to hold a lightsaber more than a blaster. In the films it's obvious that he is not a Force-Sensitive. As the quotes above show, in *A New Hope* he doesn't believe in the Force. And in *The Force Awakens*, he admits that the Force, the Jedi are all real. Even at that point, he didn't have an interest in becoming a Jedi. **Why is that though he admits that the Force and the Jedi were all true, he still did not become a Jedi?**

Comment: I can admit that magic is real, but it doesn't make me a wizard.

Comment: You need to be Force-sensitive to be a Jedi. He's not Force-sensitive.

Comment: Well, it's like a guy who hates sports eventually becoming a fan. Doesn't mean he has ANY aptitude for it, or even if he did, that the timing and life situation are right for it.

Comment: Because he didn't undergo the training

Comment: But why didn't he undergo training

Comment: "He is too old. Yes. Too old to begin the training." - Yoda

Comment: He is not that very much old

Comment: Because he wasn't force sensitive

Comment: Btw have you looked at our [tour] and maybe take a look at [ask]

Comment: Why he wasn't  force sensitive

Comment: Maybelline doesn't help here. Either you're born with Force Sensitivity or you're not.

Comment: He's not force sensitive because... he wasn't born force sensitive?

Comment: @Null - That was established *later* in the film series and is a retcon.

Comment: For most of his life he doesn't even believe the Force exists and you wonder why he doesn't want to go through years of training on an isolated swamp world with the last of the Jedi masters eating Degobah muck and having mynocks flying overhead making a racket and pooping on him while he stands on his head with a small green person croaking at him all day long instead of freely flying through the galaxy in one of the best ships in the galaxy with his best friend? I mean... Why **would** he want to be a Jedi?

Answer (score 15):

You just answered your own question.

> it's obvious that he is not a Force-Sensitive.

Jedi are force-sensitives, Solo was not. Therefore he would not have been able to use the force.

> A Jedi was a **Force-sensitive** individual, most often a member of
>   the Jedi Order, who studied, served, **and used the mystical energies
>   of the Force**; usually, the light side of the Force.
>   <sub>[Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi)</sub>

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

A being is either born with or without force sensitivity. Which is decided at the molecular level.

> An indication of Force-sensitivity was the quantity of midi-chlorians
>   in a subject's cells, with Force-sensitives possessing an above average number of these microscopic lifeforms in comparison to the
>   general population of the galaxy.
>   <sub>[Force-sensitive](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force-sensitive)</sub>

> **ANAKIN:** Master, sir...I've been wondering...what are midi-chlorians?
>   **QUI-GON:** Midi-chlorians are a microscopic lifeform that reside within all living cells and communicates with the Force.
>   [...]
>   **QUI-GON:** Without the midi-chlorians, life could not exist, and we would have no knowledge of the Force. They continually speak to you, telling you the will of the Force.
>   <sub>Episode 1: The Phantom Menace</sub>

Solo was not born with enough midi-chlorians to communicate with the force (i.e. force sensitivity). Though due to marrying Leia Skywalker, his son did have force sensitivity.

Comment: You might want to mention that one can only be born Force-sensitive, and that Han wasn't born so.

Comment: Why he wasn't a force -sensitive?

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar - Because he was born without midichlorians.....

Comment: Your answer might also benefit from quoting sources other than Wikia.

Comment: @Gallifreyan except that this is all accurate...

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar Even before midi-chlorians in the old RP game, you either were force-sensitive or you weren't.

Comment: @ErinThursby Accuracy is one concern; cross-verification (or whatever it's called is the other). I can say something, but I have to back it up, don't I?

Answer (score 11):

### Retcon alert! Han *could* have become a Jedi if Lucas hadn't changed his mind about how a Jedi accesses the Force.

When Lucas conceptualised the original Star Wars: A New Hope film, his thinking was that *anyone* was capable of accessing the Force and that it simply required the right training and the right mindset. Han's inability to become a Jedi wasn't because he lacked any *physiological* abilities, it was because he was a braggart, a louche and a skeptic.

> **Kasdan:** *The Force was available to anyone who could hook into it?*
>
> **Lucas:** *Yes, **everybody can do it.***
>
> **Kasdan:** ***Not just the Jedi?***
>
> **Lucas:** ***It’s just the Jedi who take the time to do it.***
>
> **Marquand:** *They use it as a technique.*
>
> **Lucas:** *Like Yoga. **If you want to take the time to do it, you can do it;** but the ones that really want to do it are the ones who are
> into that kind of thing. Also like karate.*
>
> <sub><sup>[StarWars.com - SO WHAT THE HECK ARE MIDI-CHLORIANS?](http://www.starwars.com/news/so-what-the-heck-are-midi-chlorians)</sup></sub>

and

> *"You have to come to learn it. It’s not something you just get. It
> takes many, many years…**Anyone who studied and worked hard could learn
> it**. But you would have to do it on your own.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[StarWars.com - SO WHAT THE HECK ARE MIDI-CHLORIANS?](http://www.starwars.com/news/so-what-the-heck-are-midi-chlorians)</sup></sub>

---

Over time, Lucas evolved the idea that the Force was mediated by midi-chlorians, microscopic entities that live inside cells. At that point, Force abilities became not just a matter of training (although a modicum of training is needed to unlock those abilities) but also that the person is required to have a certain level of midi-chlorians in their system. **Han lacks these. His midi-chlorian count is very low indeed (Lucas joked that it was zero at one point), and hence can't be a Jedi.**

> *“In Anakin’s
> case, there are, instead of one or two or three midi-chlorians in each
> cell, there’s like a thousand. It’s unbelievable how many
> midi-chlorians are in there.”*
>
> *“I’m assuming that the
> midi-chlorians are a race that everybody knows about [in the world of
> Star Wars]. The way you interact and interface with this larger energy
> field [the Force] is through the midi-chlorians, which are sensitive
> to the energy. They are at the core of your life, which is the cell,
> the living cell. They are in a symbiotic relationship with the cell.
> And then, because they’re all interconnected as one, they can
> communicate with the larger Force field. That’s how you deal with the
> Force.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[StarWars.com - SO WHAT THE HECK ARE MIDI-CHLORIANS?](http://www.starwars.com/news/so-what-the-heck-are-midi-chlorians)</sup></sub>

and

> **Lucas:** ***"Han Solo has no midi-chlorians. He’s a zombie!”***
>
> <sub><sup>[StarWars.com - SO WHAT THE HECK ARE MIDI-CHLORIANS?](http://www.starwars.com/news/so-what-the-heck-are-midi-chlorians)</sup></sub>

Comment: +1 for the M-canon acceptable answer. Before midi-chlorians were written in, it still wouldn't have been remotely close to Han's character to become a Jedi. He's a self-avowed scoundrel.

Answer (score 1):

Technically in a now-defunct and non-canon comic strip taking place about 5 years after the end of *The Return of the Jedi*, Han came in contact with a crystal that magnified one’s force potential (note I said "magnified" not "granted") with which he tried to destroy a temple with it.  It is my belief that while Han isn’t gifted in the force department he is still touched by it.

I have tried in vain to find this comic again, I’ve only ever seen it in a private collection, but if anyone has seen or heard of what I’m talking about (and I don’t hold high hopes) I’d love to know... it’s probably long forgotten by most fans, just like the star wars Christmas special, except not as meme worthy XD

Comment: If you want to find this again you could always ask a [[tag:story-identification]] question on it.